# Product of the digits occupying the five consecutive positions is divisible by $5$.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of permutations of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ taken all at a time without repetition in which the product of the digits occupying the five consecutive positions is divisible by $5$.

In this question,i think $5$ is to be fixed at a place and rest of the digits is to be permuted.But i can not conclude the answer.Please help me.

Comment: It's a unclear what you mean by "*the* five consecutive positions". As $5$ is prime it will have to be one of the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the product of any 5 consecutive positions must be divisible by 5, 5 must either occupy position 4 or position 5, and the rest permuted around it, thus $2\cdot7!$ permutations

Comment: why only position 4 or position 5 sir,in the product of digits,order is irrelevant.Isn't it?,@true blue anil

Comment: The product of the numbers in any **five consecutive positions** is to be divisible by 5, so 5 must figure in all sets of five consecutive positions, hence needs to be in position 4 or 5.